# javascript change image radio button

Tags: javascript

I need to be able to change image when I click on a radio button I did some research and for some reason it doesn't work. I dont have a lot of knowledge with javascript so maybe I am missing something. I cant use jquery for this.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
 
<script>
      
          
        function check_value(fieldvalue) {
            case 1:
                document.getElementById("displayimages").innerHTML = "<img src='images/Images1.jpg'>";
                break;
            case 2:
                document.getElementById("displayimages").innerHTML = "<img src='images/Images2.jpg'>";
                break;
            case 3:
                document.getElementById("displayimages").innerHTML = "<img src='images/Images3.jpg'>";
                break;
            }
        
</script>
 
</head>

<body>

<form name="ImageSelect">
  <input type="radio" name="field" value="one" onclick="check_value(1)"/> Images 1<br />
  <input type="radio" name="field" value="two" onclick="check_value(2)"/> Images 2<br />
  <input type="radio" name="field" value="three" onclick="check_value(3)"/> Images 3<br />
</form>


<div id="displayimages"></div>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What didn't work? Can you be more specific and provide a [mcve]?

Comment: When I press the radio button the image is not display.

Comment: Ok, so there's an unexpected token `catch`. Why might that be? Think about where catch can be used.

Comment: For future reference, please do some research before asking a question. That's why I've downvoted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`case` statements must be inside a `switch`.

```
function check_value ( fieldvalue ) {
    switch ( fieldvalue ) {
        case 1:
            ...
    }
}
```

In your case you could also write your function this way:

```
function check_value ( fieldvalue ) {
    document.getElementById( "displayimages" ).innerHTML = "<img src='images/Images" + fieldvalue + ".jpg'>"
}
```